# Understanding and Using "Service Layers" - .NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, service-layer

I am currently in an internship and from what I have been learning the controller in MVC should solely be used for traffic, and only for traffic. I have also been told about something called a "service layer", which sounds like the spot where I should be doing any data/business logic for the controller.

I have been searching around for examples and tutorials on this but I am not finding anything that dumbs it down enough for me, as I have only just learned MVC about a month ago. I am wondering if someone would be able to explain and show me how I would transfer the following `ActionResult Index` business logic into a "service layer".

```
public class LakerLegendsController : Controller
{    
    string pathway1 = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/Announcement1.txt");
    string pathway2 = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/Announcement2.txt");
    string pathway3 = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/Announcement3.txt");
    private MoviesEntities db = new MoviesEntities();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Setting some ViewBag texts from announcement files.
    string text1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathway1);
    ViewBag.TextHTML1 = text1;

    string text2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathway2);
    ViewBag.TextHTML2 = text2;

    string text3 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathway3);
    ViewBag.TextHTML3 = text3;


    // Following pulls some XML information
    XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(@"http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/rss.xml");


    var LoLtitles = from service in xmlFile.Descendants("item")
            select (string)service.Element("title");
    var LoLlinks = from service in xmlFile.Descendants("item")
             select (string)service.Element("link");
    var LoLdescriptions = from service in xmlFile.Descendants("item")
             select (string)service.Element("description");
    var LoLDates = from service in xmlFile.Descendants("item")
              select (string)service.Element("pubDate");

    var servicing = LoLdescriptions.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        servicing[i] = Regex.Replace(Server.HtmlDecode(servicing[i]), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
    }

    ViewBag.titles = LoLtitles.ToArray();
    ViewBag.links = LoLlinks.ToArray();
    ViewBag.descriptions = servicing;
    ViewBag.dates = LoLDates.ToArray();

    // Pulls the DB Table
    var users = db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1);
    return View(users.ToList());
}
}
```

All that this code is doing is returning a DB table, along with some extra logic which pulls an XML file and parses some of its information.

I am wondering how I could turn this specific example into using a service layer (or whatever it is I should use for the logic). Please try to make this as simple as possible, as I am still new to MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Service Layer defines set of available operations in regards with interfacing client layers i.e. encapsulates the application's business logic. They are just a separate classes in different class library (or namespace) those are independent of MVC framework infrastructure which can be used by ASP.NET Web API or WCF.

> I have been searching around for examples and tutorials on this but I
>   am not finding anything that dumbs it down enough for me

Here is good example of very well known music store. This may help you getting through Service Layer with DI [Injecting a Controller MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvcdependencyinjection_topic2)

Purpose of service layer is for decoupling and maintainability